# Always getting "Not found" message when using mapbox datasets api

Tags: json, mapbox

When making a request to the MapBox API to create a new dataset we keep getting a response 404 {
  "name": "foo",
  "description": "bar"
}.

We are sending the code: 
curl -X POST “https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/username?access_token=TOKEN” \
-d @mapboxtest.json \
--header “Content-Type:application/json

Comment: Welcome. You might [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about our process. We don't mark things solved in titles or posts. Instead, use the tools to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved!!!

It's just a wierd message. My token key is not allowed to change datasets, that was the problem. It was the default public key!